# Nested json data value to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

convert nested json row value (json) to new dataframe

```
val rd1= spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("data.json")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val ds1= rd1.select("alpha._id", "alpha.Description", "alpha.Sub-Tower","alpha.Tower","alpha.input_data") // 

ds1.show()// it gives only single row with array in each column values  instead need table of 4 rows
```

## my approach 1

```
val ds2=ds1
  .withColumn("Description", explode(col("Description")))
  .withColumn("Tower",data explode(col("Tower")))
  .withColumn("input_data", explode(col("input_data")))
  .withColumn("Sub-Tower", explode(col("Sub-Tower")))
  .withColumn("_id", explode(col("_id"))) 

println(ds2.count()) /// the json array lenngth is  4 it is giving 1025 incorrect output
```

#### input

```
{

  "name": "raxvsdbsd",
  "stack": "raw",
  "threshold": "50",

  "alpha": [
    {
      "_id": "27",
      "input_data": "alpha beta gamma",
      "Tower": "A B C",
      "Description": "a b,c",
      "Sub-Tower": "crt"
    },
    {
      "_id": "91",
      "input_data": "alpha beta gamma",
      "Tower": "A B C",
      "Description": "a b,c",
      "Sub-Tower": "crt"
    },
     {
      "_id": "21",
      "input_data": "alpha beta gamma",
      "Tower": "A B C",
      "Description": "a b,c",
      "Sub-Tower": "crt"
    },

     {
      "_id": "29",
      "input_data": "alpha beta gamma",
      "Tower": "A B C",
      "Description": "a b,c",
      "Sub-Tower": "crt"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected output :

table for alpha as below :

```
+-----------+---------+-----+---+----------------+
|Description|Sub-Tower|Tower|_id|      input_data|
+-----------+---------+-----+---+----------------+
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 27|alpha beta gamma|
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 91|alpha beta gamma|
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 21|alpha beta gamma|
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 29|alpha beta gamma|
+-----------+---------+-----+---+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the code in scala to `explode` the content of column `alpha`

```
val df = <read_your_input_file_using_spark>

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val result = df.select(explode($"alpha").as("alpha")).select("alpha.*")

result.printSchema()
result.show()
```

and the result is as follows:

```
root
 |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sub-Tower: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tower: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- input_data: string (nullable = true)

+-----------+---------+-----+---+----------------+
|Description|Sub-Tower|Tower|_id|      input_data|
+-----------+---------+-----+---+----------------+
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 27|alpha beta gamma|
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 91|alpha beta gamma|
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 21|alpha beta gamma|
|      a b,c|      crt|A B C| 29|alpha beta gamma|
+-----------+---------+-----+---+----------------+
```